# matplotlib messes up the X-axis if first or last y value is NaN/None. Is this normal?

Tags: matplotlib

After `subplot.plot([1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 10])`, `subplot.axis()` returns an x-axis that goes roughly from 1 to 3.

But after `subplot.plot([1, 2, 3], [None, None, None])`, x goes from 0 to 1.

After `subplot.plot([1, 2, 3], [8, 9, None])`, it goes from 1 to 2.

Is this normal? What should I do to get a correct chart in such a case? (for example, an empty chart spanning 1 to 3 if all `None`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("AGG")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_plot(ydata):
    fig = plt.figure()
    subplot = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    subplot.scatter([1, 2, 3], ydata)
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = subplot.axis()
    print(f"X axis goes from {x1} to {x2} when ydata={ydata}")

create_plot([8, 9, 10])
create_plot([None, None, None])
create_plot([8, 9, None])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal.

In case `ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [None, None, None])` there is no data to plot, hence the axes does not autoscale and stays at the default `[0,1]` view limits.

In case `ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [8, 9, None])`, the only data to show are `(1,8)` and `(2,9)`. Hence the x axis range is 1 to 2.

If you want to get the same x-axis limits with or without data, you can update the data limits

```
ax.update_datalim(np.c_[xdata,[0]*len(xdata)], updatey=False)
ax.autoscale()
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_plot(ydata):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    xdata = [1, 2, 3]
    ax.scatter(xdata, ydata)
    ax.update_datalim(np.c_[xdata,[0]*len(xdata)], updatey=False)
    ax.autoscale()
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = ax.axis()
    print(f"X axis goes from {x1} to {x2} when ydata={ydata}")

create_plot([8, 9, 10])
create_plot([None, None, None])
create_plot([8, 9, None])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm choosing this as the accepted answer, because it explains the issue more clearly. However @QuangHoang's answer has a simpler solution (it uses `set_xlim()`), which is what I used. Thanks a lot to both!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this is normal as `plt` will ignore `None` data. To change the limit, you could set the limit of `xaxis`:

```
def create_plot(ydata):
    xvals = [1,2,3]

    fig = plt.figure()
    subplot = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    subplot.scatter(xvals, ydata)

    # set the limit
    subplot.set_xlim(min(xvals), max(xvals))

    x1, x2, y1, y2 = subplot.axis()
    print(f"X axis goes from {x1} to {x2} when ydata={ydata}")
```